# How do I refer to an image resource from CSS in grails?

Tags: css, grails, resources

I want to refer to an image in my main stylesheet for a Grails app and I can't get it to work.  My image lives in the standard location in my Grails app...

```
project\web-app\images\outbound-blue.png
```

In my stylesheet I want to use it as a background image for a class...

```
.messageimg {
    height:17px;
    width:16px;
    background-image:url(images/outbound-blue.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This doesn't work for some reason.  My stylesheet is in the normal location too, i.e.

```
project\web-app\css\main.css
```

I get a missing image marker when I load the page in the browser.  I have checked that I have no typos in names etc.  I have also tried fiddling around with the virtual path in the url, but I can't figure out what I need to put in there to make this work in Grails.

I don't want to use GSP and insert an IMG tag into my code because I want to control the image through styles.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had no problems using the solution Jared described below. After changing it, are you sure the browser hadn't cached the previous style and just didn't update? What happens when you use something like Firebug to inspect the element on which you expect the background to be applied?

Comment: Also, I noticed you referred to 'outbound-blue' in your initial example and 'inbound-blue' in your example updated after trying Jared's suggestion. A mistype there? Just trying to find little things that may have caused your missing background. :)

Comment: had the same problem. the reason why this does not work is because you forgot the quotes in url. Write  background-image:url('images/outbound-blue.png');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding "../" at the beginning of the URI. For example:

```
../images/outbound-blue.png
```

The "../" at the start of the URI tells the browser to go up one level to the parent directory then look in the `images` directory. Currently you have it set up to look for a subdirectory called `images` in the directory containing stylesheets.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly with something other then the path. My suggestion was taken streight from the default style sheet created with grails apps. Maybe you should retag or re ask the question to be a more general CSS question?

Comment: You were right Jared.  Something was caching the page.  CTRL-F5 in the browser didn't correct it, I had to bounce the grails server to get the new stylesheet to show up.

I suspect I had fixed it before I even posted the question.  I'm not sure what the rules are about when to re-start grails.  Controller changes seem to need it.

Comment: How can I use css and images from a Grails plugin?

Answer (score 20):

A more portable way to specify image locations is to use the resource() function:

```
.messageimg {
    height:17px;
    width:16px;
    background-image:url('${resource(dir: "images", file: "outbound-blue.png")}');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most useful way. It lets you reach in to plugins as well, which can be rather needed more often than not.

Comment: Will this work inside of a `.css` file, or only when using inline styles within the view/`.gsp` page?

Comment: It only works inside the `.gsp` file, not a `.css ` file @aroth

Answer (score 4):

Be aware though. Using `$resource{...` does not work within a referenced .css file. You need to add a `style` element.

Comment: There is a way to pass a "stand-alone" CSS file through Grails' template engine with surprisingly little impact on the application, check this article: http://www.wthr.us/2010/02/16/preprocessing-css-in-grails/ - was the perfect solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would reference a resource in a style sheet as a relative url.  The url of your image should be relative to the CSS file's location. So `../images/outbound-blue.png` from `/appName/css/main.css` will be referencing `/appName/images/outbound-blue.png`

If you are still having issues, You can debug this by using a tool like firebug to inspect the page and verify each step in your style.
Verify that:

- The item that you think is being styled is picking up the styles.
- The image that you are referencing can be accessed both manually, and via firebug.
- The css file that you are loading isn't cached and is actually refreshed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seemed to be that the browser was looking into

`http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/assets/images/<background-image-name>`

which seems correct but if you inspect other images on the page, they render from the path

```
http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/assets/background-image-name
```

So, just by excluding images in your path-name should fix the issue. However, this is just a work around which I am sure would have a better explaination and a solution. Cheers.