# Grails - Get image resource in CSS

Tags: css, grails

Is there a way to use something like ${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'myimage.png')} in a CSS file with grails? I can define URLs normally in the CSS, but it's not as portable.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your your css file extension from ".css" to ".css.gsp". You can then use resource tags inside these files.

Comment: I would much prefer the final file have a .css file extension. It looks hackish to have a .css file end in .gsp.

Comment: Yeah.. it would look that way. Also, your editor wont recognize your file as css file, you will loose auto-completion feature. But if you need to use grails tags inside your css, that's the only option available(as far as i know).

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs are rewritten by the resources plugin. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193932/how-do-i-refer-to-an-image-resource-from-css-in-grails).

If you want to use groovy code and grails plugins within the CSS, you can use the [GSP Resources Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-resources).

Comment: Your links work for .gsp files, but I'm looking for a solution for .css files.

Comment: If you must use grails/groovy code within a static resource, you need the plugin from the second link. It was written to address the exact question you asked.

Comment: I followed the steps in http://mckenfra.github.io/gsp-resources/docs/guide/single.html, but the style wasn't getting called. If I went to /css/mystyle.css.gsp, it would redirect to /static/css/mystyle.css, which gave a 404 error. /css/mystyle.css also gave a 404 error. The error happened with both methods mentioned in the docs for setting up ApplicationResources.

Comment: You may be tripping on an annoying order-of-operations bug in the resources plugin. [See here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-218).